# In Scrapy Pipeline, return super().process_item means what?

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

i found a scrapy piplines codes :

```
class SomeImagePipeline(ImagePipeline):
    ....
    ....
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return super(SomeImagesPipeline, self).process_item(item, spider)
```

what does means " super(SomeImagesPipeline, self).process_item(item, spider) " ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [standard documentation on super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super), super method:

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

So, `return super(SomeImagesPipeline, self).process_item(item, spider)` calls the `process_item` method of base class i.e. `ImagePipeline` and returns its return object.

Comment: super().process_item(item,spider) is same as super(SomeImagesPipeline, self).process_item(item, spider) ?